# How to set the selected value in an Android Spinner

Tags: android, widget, spinner

I want the spinner to show the value that I have selected (and that I have also stored in sharedPreferences). I want this to happen when I resume the activity after the method onPause() is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OnResume method of the activity 
Get the value from the shared preferences and decide which index it is in the adapter and use spinnerObject.setSelection(INDEX)